# Generated web service client doesn't match wdsl

Tags: java, eclipse, service, wsdl

After developing a web service on Eclipse, based on Axis1 and JBoss, I deploy it and test it with soapUI. It works perfectly.

Eclipse generates a wsdl file which I use in Eclipse's new web service client wizard to create an application client that consumes the web service. It generates the client code perfectly, but when I invoke some operations, I get the following error:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element int ClassX - variableName.

How's that even possible? Everything was done using Eclipse's webservices tools for both generating the web service and the client. How can I check that my web service is getting generated correctly? What conditions should a complex object that is sended over a web service follow?

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2545

Is this along the same lines as your problem? I remember the wsdl axis tool sometimes mismatches element names, so instead of

```
elemField.setFieldName("**EventID**");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "EventID"));
```

it comes out as

```
elemField.setFieldName("**eventID**");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "EventID"));
```